# Android Data binding issue Binding adapter call twice

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have simple imageview in my layout and I have a api which gives me a image url. I integrate Data binding in my layout. Now after parsing the api I'm setting the model through this line `binding.setUserinfo(memberObj.getMemberdata());`

Now I have also a binding adapter where imgurl code is written. Now the custom binding adapter calls **twice** when activity start and after parsing the api.

Now i want to notify the UI after api has been successfully parsed.

**Here is my code of xml activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data class="MainBinding">
        <variable
            name="userinfo"
            type="com.myapplication.retrofit.pojo.ImgTest"/>
    </data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.retrofit.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        app:image_url="@{userinfo.imgUrl}"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**Here is my Pojo: ImgTest.java**

```
public class ImgTest extends BaseObservable {

    String imgUrl;
    @Bindable
    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.imgUrl);
    }
}
```

**Here is my CustomBinder.java**

```
public class CustomBinders {
    private static final String TAG = "CustomBinders";
    @BindingAdapter({"image_url"})
    public static void loadImageWithOUtProgressBar(ImageView view, String imageUrl){

        Log.d(TAG, "before loadImageWithOUtProgressBar: "+imageUrl);
        Log.d(TAG, "after loadImageWithOUtProgressBar: "+imageUrl);
        Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(view);
    }

}
```

**Here is MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    RestManager mManager;
    MainBinding binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
        mManager = new RestManager();
        Call<ResponseBody> getUserInfo = mManager.getService().getUserInfo("25","sell");
        getUserInfo.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                int sc = response.code();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+sc);

                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    ImgTest img = new ImgTest();
                        try {
                            String res = response.body().string();
                            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(res);             
                            JSONObject obj = jobj.getJSONObject("memberdata");                           
                            String imgUrl = "";
                            imgUrl = obj.getString("prifile_picture");
                            img.setImgUrl(imgUrl);
                            binding.setUserinfo(img);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please let know how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have no more idea about data binding but when you make a call then open one dialog then after when response is finish then dismiss this dialog

Comment: That is not the solution

Comment: `binding.setUserinfo(img);` is enough to refresh your ui, if it doesn't work you can try `binding.executePendingBindings();` after that.

Comment: My UI is updating that is not the issue. The issue is when activity start at that time CustomBinder calls for setiing the img where the value is **null**.

After successful response of Api then **again** custom binder call with proper value when i set `binding.setUserinfo(img);`

Comment: yes that is desired behaviour, whenever view is created it will load all the data, and after changing its value again that view will be created. You can put somecondition in your `BindingAdapter` regarding `null` value, or else put that condition in xml itself

Comment: Yes I can do that but really is their no way to solve that issue?

Comment: Hey Ravi check the answer written by @George it's osm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Ravi says in the comments, it is working as intended. After you create the initial binding, the values should be set to the values as they are. If you haven't set anything then they will be set to null.

You can change the behavior by explicitly telling the binding to not bind. Add an `OnRebindCallback` to the binding:

```
private OnRebindCallback<ActivityMainBinding> delayRebindCallback = 
        new OnRebindCallback<ActivityMainBinding>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreBind(ActivityMainBinding binding) {
        return false;
    }
};

// ... and then after creating the binding ...
binding.addOnRebindCallback(delayRebindCallback);
```

In your onResponse (assuming it is on the UI thread):

```
binding.removeOnRebindCallback(delayRebindCallback);
binding.setUserinfo(img);
binding.executePendingBindings();
```

If it isn't on the UI thread, you will have to post an executable to run the `binding.executePendingBindings()` on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you so much @George . I just love to see your videos on the #youtube channel. 
Just one thing please add this line to your answer "Please declare `OnRebindCallback delayRebindCallback;`"